# Fuzzy lookup config xlm - defining a transformation table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using the Fuzzy-lookup add in. It works fine but there is a feature that is mentioned in the documentation that allows you to specify a third table (with row names To and From). It is described in the readme documentation (last line of this paragraph):

Transformations greatly increase the power of Jaccard similarity by allowing tokens to be converted from one string to another. For instance, one might know that the name “Bob” can be converted to “Robert”; that “USA” is the same as “United States”; or that “Missispi” is a misspelling of “Mississippi”. There are many classes of such transformations that Fuzzy Lookup handles automatically such as spelling mistakes (using Edit Transformations described below), string prefixes, and string merge/split operations. **You can also specify a table containing your own custom transformations.**

When you hit the configure button, and go to the TransformationRowSetnames - it says "The name of the excel table or rowset table manually defined in the config XML containing transformation rules. The table should have two string columsn named From and To."

When I go to the config XML by clicking Advanced I am unable to see where and how to specify this other table. I have tried adding the name of the table to

but when I put the name of the table (with the proper string colums" ) I get an error message.

I am able to do this with PowerQuery BUT powerQuery does not give the %similarity.

Can anyone figure out how to manually define this table in the config XLM?

Answer (score 0):

Tough question.

You might try here - this Bill Jelen guy seems to know what he is talking about

```
https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-use-fuzzy-match-in-Excel
```

Also have a look at the Portfolio.xlsx example included in the add-on install folder. It defines and uses such a "from" and "to" table.